# Visual Studio 2010 / 2012 Load Test Error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, testing, visual-studio-2012

When I try to open a load test inside a test project, I receive the error

```
"The parameter is incorrect (Exception from HRESULT:0x80070057(E_INVALIDARG))"
```

So I cannot open any test to customize, webtest, load test..

The only difference I experiment is that in VS2012, right clicking the load test file, 
it gives me the option "Open (Shell)", clicking it, an instance of VS2010 is opened
with the test selected and loaded in a temporary solution, but if I try to open 
that test in a normal VS2010 instance I receive the same error as above

```
"The parameter is incorrect (Exception from HRESULT:0x80070057(E_INVALIDARG))"
```

Any idea?
thanks in advance

Comment: This is the kind of problem you should report at connect.microsoft.com.  You'l need to give them better info than you did in this question or they will quickly close it with "no repro".  At a minimum the stack trace of the exception and a copy of the test project, preferably a minidump of devenv.exe

Comment: Same problem here, did you find an answer?

Comment: I am facing the same problem when opening a Web Test. Could you guys find a solution/cause of this issue?